# PSQL Connect Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

Ever since I installed pgAdmin 4, I've been getting issues with Rails projects. Just like this one:

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Couldn't create 'db_name' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

The steps I've done to fix the issues are:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db_name TO user_name;


GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_name TO user_name;
```

But I still am getting the error above every time I run `rails db:setup`.
What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already try with give permisison to the schema also?

> GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schemaname TO username;

I got from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169264/pgadmin-getting-detail-user-does-not-have-connect-privilege-error) if you want to learn further.

Answer (score -1):

> FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
>
> GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db_name TO user_name;

You need to GRANT CONNECT to the database you are trying to connect to.  Based on the error message, that would be "postgres", not "db_name".

Or change the config so you don't try to connect to "postgres" in the first place.

Comment: I ran this but I still wasn't able to run the `rails db:setup` : `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "db_name" TO "user_name";`

Comment: "db_name" and "postgres" are different things.  Even when in double quotes.

Comment: Those are just pseudo names of the real db name and username. C'mon.

Comment: Are the real names of "postgres" and "db_name" equal to each other? If you falsify your ERROR messages, it is up to you to translate our advice back into reality.  Note that those are both attempted database names, neither one of them is a username.